# I am using a strtotime function but I need also my start date to be included in the array list

Tags: while-loop, strtotime

I am using a strtotime function but I need also my start date to be included in the array list
here is the code snippet

```
while (strtotime($startDate) <= strtotime($newEnddate)) { 
            $newStartDate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startDate)));
            $dates = array(
                'startdate' => $newStartDate,
                'enddate' => $newStartDate
            );
            //$this->ddc_get_res($dates);
            $startDate = $newStartDate;
        }
```

then result of this is

```
array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-16',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-16',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-17',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-17',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-18',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-18',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-19',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-19',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-20',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-20',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-21',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-21',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-22',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-22',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-23',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-23',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-24',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-24',
)
```

but my expected result is this

```
array (
 'startdate' => '2016-10-15',
       'enddate'   => '2016-10-15'
     (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-16',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-16',
    )array (
      'startdate' => '2016-10-17',
      'enddate' => '2016-10-17',
    )array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-18',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-18',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-19',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-19',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-20',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-20',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-21',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-21',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-22',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-22',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-23',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-23',
)array (
  'startdate' => '2016-10-24',
  'enddate' => '2016-10-24',
)
```

any ideas on this thank you will appreciate any help available

Comment: Please re-phase your question, also provide initial values of variables in context.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, all you have to do is move your before computing next date:

```
while (strtotime($startDate) <= strtotime($newEnddate)) { 
    $dates = array(                // moved line
        'startdate' => $startDate, // changed
        'enddate' => $startDate    // changed
    );
    $this->ddc_get_res($dates);    // moved line

    $newStartDate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startDate)));
    $startDate = $newStartDate;
}
```

Comment: its still outputs +1 to start date

Comment: What are the initials values of `$startDate` and `$newEnddate` ?